# Haskell pattern matching on a function result

Tags: haskell

I have an algebraic data type like:

```
data Toll = Vok Int Bool | Bok Int | Cokd String Char
```

and another function

```
getVal :: Int -> Toll
getVal 1 = Cokd "hello" 'c'
getVal _ = Bok 12
```

I want to call `getVal` in some function and extract the arguments of `Cokd` (if the answer was of type `Cokd`) (maybe using pattern matching).

can I do like:

```
hello :: Int -> Bool
hello x = if st == "hell" then True else False
where (Cokd st ch) = getVal x
```

I cannot use monads.

How to do that?

Comment: Do you want to pattern-match the result of `getVal`? Something like `case getVal x of { Cokd str ch -> ... }`?

Comment: can i do like in edit post above @ZhekaKozlov

Answer (score 6):

You can use `case` to pattern-match the result of `getVal`:

```
data Toll = Vok Int Bool | Bok Int | Cokd String Char

getVal :: Int -> Toll
getVal 1 = Cokd "hello" 'c'
getVal _ = Bok 12

hello :: Int -> Bool
hello x =
  case getVal x of
    Cokd st ch ->
      st == "hell"
    _ -> False
```

Or create a separate function and pattern match the argument:

```
hello :: Int -> Bool
hello =
  helloToll . getVal
  where
    helloToll (Cokd st ch) = st == "hell"
    helloToll _ = False
```

---

The example, that you've provided in the question compiles (with few modifications), but it will throw a runtime exception when you try to call `hello` with `2` (or any other value different from `1`, in which case `getValue` returns `Bok 12`, thus `(Cokd st ch) = getVal x` fails to pattern-match).

Comment: the way i show in the original post seems to compile, will it work? @igor-

Comment: it will work as long as you provide `1`'s to `hello`. other values will fail. (updated my answer)

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems totally fine, just one correction: the pattern `if <expr> then True else False` can be replaced with `<expr>`.

```
hello :: Int -> Bool
hello x = st == "hell" where (Cokd st ch) = getVal x
```

However, this code will fail for values other than `1` due to non-exhaustive pattern matching. You need to cover all cases:

```
hello :: Int -> Bool
hello x = case getVal x of
    Cokd st ch -> st == "hell"
    _ -> False
```